# link_to root appears empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails when using:

```
<h1><% link_to "Home", root_url %></h1>
```

Nothing appears inside the  tags. My routes.rb is:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'posts#index'
  resources :posts
  match "/help" => "help#index"
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot about the `=` sign:

```
<% link_to
  ^
  |
 here
```

Comment: ahhh! thank you. When should the equal sign be used and when should it not?

Comment: @bswinnerton Use `=` when you want something to be appeared on your page. If it's a condition, loops etc., you generally don't want it to leave any traces: `<% if @user %> Hello, <%= @user.name %><% end %>` - see? There's no `=` for `if` and `end`, but `@user.name` has to have `=` near it.

Comment: @bswinnerton Also take a look at squeel: http://slim-lang.com/. It simplifies the readability/manageability of your markup greatly!

Comment: I think that you put the = when you need the server to send a print order, whenever you put it or not it will process the instruction. So put it if you want to print the return of the instruction.